# Find antiderivative with given condition

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f\colon\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by  $f(x) =\max\{1, x^2\}.$ Prove that $f$ admits antiderivatives on  $\mathbb{R}$ and find one antiderivative $F$ such that  $$4F\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)-3F\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=3F(2)$$

I have used the formula with modulus to rewrite the function but I cannot think of a function whose derivative is a modulus function. How should I proceed?

Comment: Hint: $\int_0^x f(t) dt$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$.

Comment: Hint2: So is $\int_a^x f(x)dx$, for any real $a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&\text{ if }x\leqslant-1\\1&\text{ if }-1\leqslant x\leqslant1\\x^2&\text{ if }x\geqslant1,\end{cases}$$an antiderivative $a$ of $f$ is$$a(x)=\begin{cases}\frac13x^3-\frac23&\text{ if }x\leqslant-1\\x&\text{ if }-1\leqslant x\leqslant1\\\frac13x^3+\frac23&\text{ if }x\geqslant1.\end{cases}$$So, every primitive $F$ of $f$ is of the form $a+k$ for some constant $k$. An easy computation shows that the only $k$ for which the equality$$4F\left(-\frac32\right)-3F\left(\frac12\right)=3F(2)$$holds is $k=-\dfrac{28}3$.